# I Can't Generate The right AccountId from Ethereum(H160) Address

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, ethereum

I am writing a test to test evm contract instantiation using polkadot api.

I get to derive the evm account like this:

```
const alice = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice', { name: 'Alice default' });
const aliceEthAccount = addressToEvm(alice.addressRaw);
```

where `addressToEvm` is an helper function from @polkadot/util-crypto

This piece of code from [frontier](https://github.com/PureStake/frontier/blob/master/frame/evm/src/lib.rs#L533) does the conversion from H160 to AccountId on chain

```
fn into_account_id(address: H160) -> AccountId32 {
        let mut data = [0u8; 24];
        data[0..4].copy_from_slice(b"evm:");
        data[4..24].copy_from_slice(&address[..]);
        let hash = H::hash(&data);

        AccountId32::from(Into::<[u8; 32]>::into(hash))
 }
```

But then when i feed the `aliceEthAccount` to my extrinsic to instantiate the evm contract, i get an address which does not correspond to my alice substrate address, which makes the origin wrong and also funds cannot be withdrawn from that wrong generated address.

Am i missing something? or is the way i am generating the H160(ethereum account) address wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t Alice or Bob in H160.

Use these instead:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alith",
        "p": "0x02509540919faacf9ab52146c9aa40db68172d83777250b28e4679176e49ccdd9f",
        "s": "0x5fb92d6e98884f76de468fa3f6278f8807c48bebc13595d45af5bdc4da702133"
    },
    {
        "name": "Baltathar",
        "p": "0x033bc19e36ff1673910575b6727a974a9abd80c9a875d41ab3e2648dbfb9e4b518",
        "s": "0x8075991ce870b93a8870eca0c0f91913d12f47948ca0fd25b49c6fa7cdbeee8b"
    },
    {
        "name": "Charleth",
        "p": "0x0234637bdc0e89b5d46543bcbf8edff329d2702bc995e27e9af4b1ba009a3c2a5e",
        "s": "0x0b6e18cafb6ed99687ec547bd28139cafdd2bffe70e6b688025de6b445aa5c5b"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dorothy",
        "p": "0x02a00d60b2b408c2a14c5d70cdd2c205db8985ef737a7e55ad20ea32cc9e7c417c",
        "s": "0x39539ab1876910bbf3a223d84a29e28f1cb4e2e456503e7e91ed39b2e7223d68"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ethan",
        "p": "0x025cdc005b752651cd3f728fb9192182acb3a9c89e19072cbd5b03f3ee1f1b3ffa",
        "s": "0x7dce9bc8babb68fec1409be38c8e1a52650206a7ed90ff956ae8a6d15eeaaef4"
    },
    {
        "name": "Faith",
        "p": "0x037964b6c9d546da4646ada28a99e34acaa1d14e7aba861a9055f9bd200c8abf74",
        "s": "0xb9d2ea9a615f3165812e8d44de0d24da9bbd164b65c4f0573e1ce2c8dbd9c8df"
    }
]
```

These built in keys can also be found at https://github.com/polkadot-js/common.